# Can I travel to Pakistan on an old, not machine readable, Pakistani passport?

Tags: passports, pakistani-citizens, biometric-passports

I have a valid, expired, old Pakistani passport that is not machine readable. Can I travel to Pakistan on this passport?

Comment: Pakistan may let you in after thoroughly vetting you, but you may not be able to pass through exit controls if your departing country had them and the airline company may not let you on board. Where do you live and do you have dual citizenship with at least one valid passport?

Comment: How can a passport be both "valid" and "expired?"

Comment: Your best option is to go to embassy and get the passport renewed. Although Pakistan will let you in after vetting and verification, Airlines can deny boarding and its too much hassle and risk.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  Putting on hold.